# Retain ActionForm values without modifying mapping

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

There is a page1 with text input box and button, page1 mapping is configured in struts (1.0). User enter values into text box, then click on button to get more inputs, this button take user to another page2 (popup page) with different mapping to select additional input. After selecting additional input, page2 submit action redirect user to page1 again keeping additional input in request, that can be read by jsp looking into scope as request. However the existing entered values lost which was entered in the text box, as page2 refreshes the page1 after redirect and hence form lost the values. I tried keeping in hidden field but that did not work. Is there any way to retain the values without modifying page1 mapping as this change needs to be added in lot many pages so I wan to avoid touching the page1 form.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep values in request attributes to prevent losing values

```
request.setAttribute("param", value);
```

and then get them using attribute and check it exists

```
value = request.getAttribute("param");
```

Comment: In case of page validation, request value may lost as page refresh again.

Comment: you can add in case of error add from parameter sent